# Armature moves mirrored objects

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, rigging, armature

So I sculped a body out of several objects and half of it's mirrored. When I parent the armature to one of the objects, as I move the armature, it will move the object alongside it's mirrored part. *How do I stop that?*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2QutynfhiM

I think this might answer your question

Comment: apply the mirror?

Comment: apply the mirror